# Why is this profile missing in the options of an org-wide email address and also the profile list in setup?

Tags: profile, customer-community, guest-user, custom-profile, org-wide-email

We have a custom profile called **Customer Community Profile**.  User license is *Guest User License*.

[image]

We also have an org-wide email address from which certain emails are sent via Apex.

I need to allow the profile to use that email address, as guest community users will now also be sending a particular email.

The problem is that the profile is not available for selection to allow use of the org-wide email address.

Then I went looking for the profile in the overall list in setup and it's not there either.

[image]

Is there something about this profile that makes it so obscure?

I can get to the profile via a user which employs it.  And I looked for the profile in setup via a full, unfiltered list view.

Comment: FYI - the Profile is located under `Setup | Sites | Manage Public Access`

Answer (score 3):

Guest User profiles are [limited in nature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_guest_policies_timelines.htm&type=5). They are unauthenticated Community users, and as such, have restricted permissions compared to a normal, logged in user, including what kind of data/objects they can access, and what they can do. I don't see a specific entry stating that they can't use org-wide email addresses, but since they have read-only access to everything, it makes sense that they can't send emails, either.

Comment: I tested it and they can send emails.  But the only workaround I knew of to get to that point is to configure the org-wide email (if the outgoing email in question is using it) with 'Allow All Profiles to Use this From Address' selected, which I was hoping to avoid.